# Get last inserted ID after inserting to associated table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

`Employees` table has a field named `current_address_id`. I'm adding a new address to `Addresses` like:

```
$updatedEntity = $this->patchEntity($employee, [
    //some other fields 
    'user'                => $userData,
    'employees_phones'    => $phonesData,
    'employees_addresses' => $addressesData,
], [
    'associated' => ['Users', 'EmployeesPhones', 'EmployeesAddresses']
]);
$this->save($updatedEntity);
```

I'm inserting the new address successfully but now I need to update `Employees.current_address_id` with the new address ID. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table::save()` returns the entity with updated ids. So store the return value in a variable and use appropriate property of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It works for me.

```
$this->ModelName->save($updatedEntity);
$lastInsertedId = $updatedEntity->id;
```

The save method will update the entity with the last insert id as long as the entity id is not already set.